# Why is it that it is self-defeating to use the posterior mode as the bayes estimator in this case?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, pareto-distribution

I am reading through an applied statistics book and in it, it makes a very luminous statement for a posterior case where the likelihood was taken from $X_1,...,X_n$ iid random variables from a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,\theta]$, for $\theta$ unknown, and for where the prior distribution is the Pareto(a,b) distribution where:

$\pi(\theta)=\frac{ba^b}{\theta^{b+1}}$ if $\theta \geq a$ and 0 if $\theta <a$,

the posterior of $\theta$ is:

$\pi(\theta |x) = Pareto(max(x_1,...,x_n,k),n+b)$.

It states that reporting the posterior mode as the Bayes estimator would **defeat** the purpose of using a Bayes estimator. Can anyone help me understand why?

I tried to calculate the posterior mode,

argmax $\frac{(n+b)( max(x_1,...,x_n,k))^{n+b}}{\theta^{n+b+1}}$. Why would reporting the posterior mode defeat the purpose of using a Bayes estimator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It defeats the purpose of a Bayes estimator because you are not defining any loss function in the first place, the expected posterior value of which is what you want to minimize in order to get a Bayes estimator. The idea of a Bayes estimator $\theta_0$ is to **minimize the expected posterior value of a given loss function, $L(\theta_0,\theta)$**, i.e., to minimize
$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta|x}[L(\theta_0,\theta)]=\int L(\theta_0,\theta) \pi(\theta|x)d\theta,$$
where $\pi(\theta|x)$ is the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given the data and any prior information, $x$. If you define, for example, $L(\theta_0,\theta)=(\theta_0-\theta)^2$, then your Bayes estimator would be the posterior mean. Different loss functions, then, lead to different bayes estimators; reporting the posterior mode and not defining the loss function in the first place is like reporting a value for a distance but not reporting what actually is that you measured and in what surface: was it the distance between two points on a sphere? A plane?, etc.

**Edit:** after I wrote this, I re-discovered this very interesting post in which I learned what I just answered in the first place some time ago: [Estimation of parameters as a mode of posterior distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31142/estimation-of-parameters-as-a-mode-of-posterior-distribution). It is way better explained than my explaination here ;-).